# using svyciprop to calculate prevalence with CI

Tags: r, survey

I'm  using R(3.6.1) to calculate prevalence using the package "survey", as i calculated prevalence with weights, my issue is that to calculate confidence interval with proportion. I'm using svyciprop() command but when it shows the confidence intervals for 97.5% it doesn't shows the value after two decimal places

```
x=svyciprop(~new_var3,small.w1)
x
```

Returns:

```
                  2.5% 97.5%
new_var3 0.0176 0.0140  0.02
```

I don't know how to fix this or there is another package or by some other way you can calculate these estimates, please help me!

Answer (score 1):

what you are seeing is printed onto the console, you can access the values like this:

```
library(survey)
data(api)
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, fpc=~fpc, data=apiclus1)
x = svyciprop(~I(ell==0), dclus1, method="li")
x
                         2.5% 97.5%
I(ell == 0) 0.021858 0.000664  0.11

values = attr(x,"ci")
values
        2.5%        97.5% 
0.0006639212 0.1077784084 
values[1]
        2.5% 
0.0006639212 
values[2]
    97.5% 
0.1077784
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, I really appreciate your help! :)